# NSLog on a NSString saved in a UITextfield

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsuserdefaults, nslog

I'm trying to save a String from a textfield.

I have a

```
IBOutlet UITextField *login;
IBOutlet UITextField *pass;
... 

@synthesize login,pass;
...
```

When I'm clicking to a button, this method is running :

```
- (IBAction) saveAuthentication: (id)sender {

    //show an error message
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login et Mot de passe" message:@"Votre login et votre mot de passe sont enregistrés."delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];[alert release];

    //extract the login from the field and put in in Log
        NSString *loginsaved = login.text;
    NSString *passsaved = pass.text;
        NSLog(@"%d", loginsaved );

        //save the login and pass in the phone
        NSUserDefaults *pref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [pref setObject:login.text forKey:@"login"];
    [pref setObject:pass.text forKey:@"pass"];

}
```

When I execute it, The Console show me  0 instead of the login that I've typed...

a hundred of thanx for the help

Comment: please add `NSAssert(login, @"Login Textfield not connected in Interface Builder");` to this method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `NSString` variable You should use below code...

```
 NSString *loginsaved = login.text;
 NSString *passsaved = pass.text;
 NSLog(@"%@", loginsaved );
```

Here in objective 
for **Integer** `%d`, **String** `%@`, **Float** `%f` is used.

Keep smiling....

Answer (score 2):

Did you link the IBOutlets to the actual elements in Interface Builder?

Sounds like login could be nil, so login.text would return nil too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
NSLog(@"%@", loginsaved );
```

Comment: possible next question: `When I execute it, the console shows nothing instead of the login that I've typed...`

Comment: @fluchtpunkt it may happen if you forgot to connect the login UITextField in your IB with the `IBOutlet UITextField *login` from your code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does because you use %d in your NSLog use %@ instead:

```
NSLog(@"%@", loginsaved );
```